# Can't download and patch ndk toolchain source using 'download-toolchain-sources.sh'

Tags: android-ndk, toolchain

Android Ndk 9, mac

```
MBA-Anton:tools asmirnov$ ./download-toolchain-sources.sh /softdev/ndk9-sources
Using git clone prefix: https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain
Cloning git repository for toolchain/build
Cloning git repository for toolchain/gmp
Cloning git repository for toolchain/mpfr
Cloning git repository for toolchain/mpc
Cloning git repository for toolchain/cloog
Cloning git repository for toolchain/isl
Cloning git repository for toolchain/ppl
Cloning git repository for toolchain/expat
Cloning git repository for toolchain/binutils
Cloning git repository for toolchain/gcc
Cloning git repository for toolchain/gdb
Cloning git repository for toolchain/python
Cloning git repository for toolchain/perl
Cloning git repository for toolchain/clang
Cloning git repository for toolchain/llvm
Cloning git repository for toolchain/compiler-rt
Cloning git repository for toolchain/mclinker
Patching toolchain sources
ERROR: Could not patch sources.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by Google in ndk-9b, now it's patching without problems

Comment: The way to get rid of this error seems to be to use the most recent ndk version. The  https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain is only guaranteed to work with the latest ndk.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run patch-sources.sh directly, with debugging enabled. With a little luck, it will give you some clues.

```
bash -x patch-sources.sh \ 
/tmp/ndk-USER/android-ndk-toolchain-DATE \
/PATH/TO/YOUR/NDK/build/tools/toolchain-patches
```

You can do the same with the download-toolchain-sources.sh script as well - this is how I got the arguments for patch-sources.sh.

You could also pass "--verbose" to either script.